# Ubuntu 12.04 Home folder showing full

Tags: 12.04, home-directory, disk-usage

I received a notification today that my home folder is full. I have a 120GB SSD with 3 partitions, /, /opt, /home (84gb).

Using the disk usage analyzer, I can only determine that there is no more than approximately 10GB being used.

I cannot find the phantom directories or folders that are taking up the space.

Is anyone able to help me free up this space?

Comment: disk usage analyzer shows hidden files and folders so this is quite strange. Try emptying your recycle bin

Comment: Seems to worked its self out after a few reboots. Now showing I have 8GB used.